# In Swift Is it possible to "swizzle" fields of a vector as in GLSL or Metal Shading Language

Tags: swift, metal

In GLSL or Metal Shading Language it is possible to do the following

```
float4 pos = float4(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
float4 swiz = pos.wzyx; // swiz = (4.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f)
float4 dup = pos.xxyy;  // dup = (1.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f)
```

also

```
float4 pos = float4(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
// pos = (5.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0)
pos.xw = float2(5.0f, 6.0f);

// pos = (8.0, 2.0, 3.0, 7.0)
pos.wx = float2(7.0f, 8.0f);

// pos = (3.0, 5.0, 9.0, 7.0)
pos.xyz = float3(3.0f, 5.0f, 9.0f);
```

This is referred to as component swizzling and permuting. I would like to implement this in Swift by operator overloading. Has anyone attempted this? I'm a bit unclear on how to approach the problem.

Comment: So do you want the convenience of being able to refer to a position in the array with a letter and being able to reorder the array that way? What exactly is it about "swizzling" that are you looking to duplicate?

Comment: Swizzling is super handy for manipulating vector components in shaders. It can be just as handy at the Swift level.  For example when converting from UIKit View space - 2D - to Metal 3D space when picking/dragging.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do the two-component swizzles for `float2`. The implementations for `float3` and `float4` are similar.

```
extension float2 {
    var xx: float2 { get { return float2(x, x) } }
    var xy: float2 { get { return self } set { self = newValue } }
    var yx: float2 { get { return float2(y, x) } set { y = newValue.x; x = newValue.y } }
    var yy: float2 { get { return float2(y, y) } }

    // ...336 additional swizzles...
}
```

A couple of observations: (1) It's not permitted in GLSL to assign to a swizzle containing duplicated components (e.g. `xxyz`); indeed, it doesn't make sense, so those are implemented as read-only properties. (2) For each vector type, there is one property that has exactly one occurrence of each component in ascending lexical order, and the corresponding property getter/setter for this property degenerate into `return self` and `self = newValue`, respectively, as shown for `xy` above.